# Como salvar arquivo em um diretorio especifico?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma pasta toda vez que o programa é executado e salvar em um local específico. Atualmente ele salva o arquivo onde o código está.

Este é meu código atual:

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as up
 
def main(args):

    camera_port1 = 0     
    nFrames = 30
     
    camera1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port1)
    data = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d__%H-%M-%S")

   file1 =("camera_1_{}.png".format(data))
         
    print ("Digite <ESC> para sair / <s> para Salvar")   
     
    emLoop= True
      
    while(emLoop):
     
        retval1, img1 = camera1.read()
        cv2.imshow('Foto1',img1)
     
        k = cv2.waitKey(100)
     
        if k == 27:
            emLoop= False
         
        elif k == ord('s'):
            cv2.imwrite(file1,img1)
            emLoop= False
     
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    camera1.release()
    
    return 0
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Mude o `file1`, para um diretório, por exemplo: `C:\\Users\\nome_do_usuario\\Envs\\ambiente_python\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\imagem.png`  mais o nome do arquivo. O código `file1 =("camera_1_{}.png".format(data))`. Ou utilizar bibliotecas para descobrir um diretório `os.path.dirname(cv2.__file__)`. Enfim, leia sobre a biblioteca [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: Windows ou Unix?

Answer (score -1):

Basta utilizar o modulo OS é bem fácil:

repare que atualmente você salva assim:

```
elif k == ord('s'):
    cv2.imwrite(file1,img1)
    emLoop= False
```

podemos acrescentar o seguinte procedimento:

```
elif k == ord('s'):
    if os.path.isdir('C:/caminho/do/diretorio'):
         cv2.imwrite('C:/caminho/do/diretorio/{}'.format(file1),img1)
    else:
        os.makedirs('C:/caminho/do/diretorio')
        cv2.imwrite('C:/caminho/do/diretorio/{}'.format(file1),img1

    emLoop= False
```

Com isso ele  irá verificar se o diretório existe. caso exista ela salva nele. caso não exista ele irá cria-lo.